# I need HTML translation

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I was researching on codepen about web animations and I cama across this html code. Please I need help tarnsaltion it into normal html code.
**HERE IS THE LINK FOR FURTHER INTERPRETATION**  https://codepen.io/noeldelgado/pen/BaogqYy

```
- w = 1240
- h = 874

.loader.df.aic.jcc
  %div
    %h1 Loading
    %h2.loader--text 0%

.demo-wrapper
  %header.df.aic.jcc
    %div
      %h1 ScrollTrigger
      %h2 demo

  %section.demo-text
    .wrapper.text
      ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

  - (1..4).each do |i|
    %section.demo-gallery
      %ul.wrapper
        - (1..rand(3..4)).each do |i|
          %li
            %img{:src=>"https://source.unsplash.com/random/#{w}x#{h}?sig=#{rand(0..206)}", :width => w, :height => h}

  %section.demo-text
    .wrapper.text
      ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

  %footer.df.aic.jcc
    %p Images from <a href="https://unsplash.com/">Unsplash</a>
```

I understand most of it but this part is the most confusing **(1..4).each do |i|**

Comment: This is NOT HTML it is HAML

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - we do not do translations.

Comment: I do not know HAML, but it is a loop of ULs from 1 to 4 where 3 or 4 LIs are created with images with random signature

Comment: you may try something like this: https://haml2erb.org/ google `haml to html` there more like this one :)

Comment: A simple (if simplistic) way of 'translating' from HAML to HTML in this case is to go into the codepen, and use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to look at the generated HTML. If you still have a problem with interpreting that, extract the bit of HTML you are having trouble with and expand your question to describe the problem alongside the actual HTML.